# trying to print barcode off printer connected to another PC on the network. Can print test page

Tags: c#, printing

I have a program to print barcodes for boxes when generated. The barcode printer is on another PC in the office on the network. I need to click my print button and then the barcode will print off.

I can print test sheets from multiple PCs on the network. But when i try to print from my code nothing happens. I plugged the printer directly into my pc and the program printed the barcode but then doesnt work over the network.

```
 else if (e.CommandName == "Print")
            {
                int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                int id = 
                Convert.ToInt32(grdList.DataKeys[rowIndex].Values[0]);
                try
                {
                    workOuterBox o = new workOuterBox();
                    o = oDL.get_workOuterBox(id);

                    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();

                    pd.PrintPage += new 
                    PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
                    this.ob_Barcode.Text 
                    =o.Barcode.bc_Barcode.ToString();
                    //pd.PrintPage += (print, args) => 
                    //pd_PrintPage(items, id, args);
                    // Set the printer name. 
                    //pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "\\NS5\hpoffice
                    pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = 
                    "\\ALPHAPC08\ZDesigner GK420d";

                    pd.Print();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write("Error: " + ex.ToString());
                }

            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    void pd_PrintPage(object print, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        long de_RecordID = Convert.ToInt32(this.de_RecordID.Value);
        cDelivery d = new cDelivery();
        d = oDL.get_cDelivery(de_RecordID);


        Font printFont = new Font("3 of 9 Barcode", 24);
        Font printFont1 = new Font("Times New Roman", 12, 
        FontStyle.Bold);

        SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

        ev.Graphics.DrawString(this.ob_Barcode.Text, printFont, br, 10, 
        85);

        ev.Graphics.DrawString(d.de_ProjectNumber, printFont1, br, 110, 
        150);          
    }
```

The result would be that my printer will print the ob_Barcode and project number.

Comment: Do you have the printer mapped to your computer? What I mean is, does it show up under Devices/Printers?

Comment: Ya Ryan it comes up as "ZDesigner GK420d on ALPHAPC08".

Comment: If your printer is listed as  "ZDesigner GK420d on ALPHAPC08"... Shouldn't you try with that PrinterName instead its network path?

Comment: Ya i forgot to put that in my question that i have tried that and it hasn't worked.

Comment: For printing to a network printer, I had to use the ip address of our print server /printer name for the PrinterName PrinterSettings option, I made a web service which handles all the work, it just takes in a document, number of pages, and other relevant info for printing. See if you can get your Network Admin to give you the ip address of your network print server or dns alias.

Comment: @alanFitzgerald So for me, I was setting the PrinterName to something like this: `\\10.9.9.99\PrinterName`, I know I had a helluva time getting all this configured. I believe we had to set up some kind of user permissions as well.

Comment: @RyanWilson thanks for the help! this worked for me in the end "\\\\ALPHAPC08\\ZDesigner GK420d". I have to set up premissions on the network now but other than that i have it printing from visual studio.

Comment: @alanFitzgerald Great job. Glad to hear you got it working.